# Calculating Third Divisor on a HyperElliptic Curve in a Finite Field

Tags: diophantine-equations, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

This is a duplicate question that I posted on Stack Overflow. I am not sure how to calculate e1, e2, c1, and c2 in Cantors algorithm for HyperElliptic Curves. I am specifically trying to add two Divisors but am not sure how to calculate certain variables needed in the algorithm.

I will link my original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039801/calculating-third-divisor-on-a-hyperelliptic-curve-in-a-finite-field) as well as post it below.

---

I have been working on a program that Calculates the third divisor, D3, on a HyperElliptic curve given D1 and D2 in a **FINITE FIELD**. I have taken many approaches and have decided on using Cantors Algorithm to do so.

In order to use Cantors Algorithm, you need two divisors written in Mumford Representation, D[u(x), v(x)]

Example: Mumford representation takes the x-values of two points and uses them as roots for u(x).

u(x) for P1(2, 5) and P2(3, 6) would be written as x^2 - 5x + 6

Then, using a system of equations, you calculate v(x) as the solution to y1 = ax1 + b = y2 = ax2 + b where you plug in the x and y values of P1 and P2 to create two equations. Doing so, you get

> 5 = a2 + b
> 6 = a3 + b

Setting these equal to each other will solve for the 'a' and 'b' values for v(x)

Now that anyone who stumbles upon this page can generally understand Mumfords form, I will get into my main problem.

Using the Example problem as a reference under the Cantors algorithm section on the [Imaginary HyperElliptic Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_hyperelliptic_curve#Cantor%27s_algorithm) wiki page, I do not know how to properly calculate 'e1', 'e2', 'c1', or 'c2'.

They use this [Example Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/116UA.png) and give the first and second divisor in Mumford representation. I am able to calculate d1 = gcd(u1, u2) but do not understand how they go from

> x - 1 = e1u1 + e2u2

to

> e1 = 1/2, e2 = -1/2

Does anyone have any idea how to properly calculate these values? I read into the Diophantine equation but have no idea how to implement something like this in python. I am using Sympy to do the rest of my calculations.

The most confusing part about this whole thing is figuring out how to do this in a **FINITE FIELD**.

I will also link this work by [Peter Birkner](http://www.hyperelliptic.org/tanja/conf/summerschool08/slides/Hyperelliptic-curves.pdf). I am specifically looking at pages 11 and 12. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing because it is not always clear whether subscripts or exponents are intended, and the meaning of the variables is unclear. Anyway, after a quick look at Birkner's slides a possibility that occurred to me is that the unclear step to you is the calculation of the gcd of two polynomials. By Bezout's identity when
$$d_1=\gcd(u_1,u_2)$$
it follows that there exists polynomials $e_1$ and $e_2$ such that the identity 
$$d_1=e_1u_1+e_2u_2$$
holds. The pair $(e_1,e_2)$ is not uniquely determined by this identity.

Comment: (cont'd) But becomes so (IIRC) if you constrain their degrees to be minimal (in a sense that I cannot reproduce without working on it a bit). Typically when you calculate the gcd (by extended Euclid) you get one pair $(e_1,e_2)$ during that calculation. And can then do a reduction round to minimize the degrees.

Comment: Alas, I cannot comment on all the details, because this is the first time I see Mumford representation of divisors (or divisor classes), and it is, as of now, anything but clear how it handles multiplicities (the negative ones in particular). Anyway, a possible source of your trouble is the point in the first comment. I brought it up only to get the ball rolling. If that was crystal clear to you, then I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Presumably you are familiar with [extended Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) because that's how modular inverses are often calculated. My interpretation is that Birkner assumes his readers know that.

Comment: [An example run of extended Euclid with polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2679525/11619)